# jQuery: filtering dropdown still showing the first element after the filtering

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to filter dropdown options based on the radiobutton selected. The filtering is happening just fine, but the problem is, after the filtering happens, the first element is still being shown.

Check the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/animeshb/7Wqfj/

```
<div id="step1">
    <input class="radiobutton" dataval="PAT" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" />
    <div>Patient</div>
    <input class="radiobutton" dataval="EMPLOYEE" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" />
    <div>Employee</div>
    <input class="radiobutton" dataval="MACHINE" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" />
    <div>Machine</div>
    <select class="selectLDlist" id="ddlAllTemplates" name="AllTemplates">
        <option value="77492|ET_07|EMPLOYEE|08/16/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|70744">EMPLOYEE</option>
        <option value="70470|testing|PAT|08/16/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|70428">Patient</option>
        <option value="70472|testing|PAT|08/12/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Patient</option>
        <option value="70472|testing|EMPLOYEE|08/13/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">EMPLOYEE</option>
        <option value="70472|testing|PAT|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Patient</option>
        <option value="70472|testing|MACHINE|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">MACHINE</option>
        <option value="70472|testing|PAT|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Patient</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function () {
    var templateType = $("#step1 input:radio[class=radiobutton]:checked").attr("dataval");

    var ddlAllTemplates = $('#ddlAllTemplates');
    var options = ddlAllTemplates.find('option');

    $('#ddlAllTemplates option').each(function () {

        var extract = $(this).attr('value').split('|')[2];
        if (extract == templateType) $(this).show();
        else $(this).hide();

    });
});
```

Comment: Can I make a suggestion that you use data attributes rather than lots of pipes?

Comment: Data attributes are definitely the way to go as I understand, and I am open to that change. I was thinking to do that the other day. But first I have to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit puzzled when checking the demos on the previous answers, none of them worked at all.
So it seems Chrome (v29) does not like at all to hide options on a select box. It might be a bug of chrome itself or not anyway I wanted to give a try and fix the problem on it.

My workaround involves in having a second "fake" select which is populated each time with the wanted options, then using the fake select to drive the real select box.

Ideally the real select should be hidden, but I kept it visible for the demo.
I tried to make less changes as possible on the HTML, so most of the changes are inside the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // When the document is ready populates the fakelist
    $('#ddlAllTemplates option').each(function (index) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'option-'+index);
        $(this).clone().attr('value', this.id).appendTo('#fakelist'); 
    });
});

$('.radiobutton').change(function () {
    var found = false; // Need this for later to find the first matching option
    var templateType = $(this).attr("dataval");

    $('#fakelist').html(''); // Empty the fakelist

    $('#ddlAllTemplates option').each(function (index) {
        var extract = $(this).attr('value').split('|')[2];      

        if (extract == templateType) {
            // Clone and push the option on the fakelist
            $(this).clone().attr('value', this.id).appendTo('#fakelist'); 

            if (!found) {
                found = true;
                $(this).prop('selected',true);
            }

        }

    });
});

$('#fakelist').change(function () {
    // And select the appropriate ID using the value from the fakelist option.
    var selected = $(this).children('option:checked').attr('id');
    $('#'+selected).prop('selected',true);
});
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edYHT/

**EDIT**
I've gone ahead and made a demo with my personal approach to the problem, always uses a second select box, but in this demo the second select box becomes the real one, and the previous one is just a source of data (at this time probably I would build an AJAX script to get data from a database and query every time I change the box, probably caching the data.)

This allows the second box to be sent to the form and to reduce greatly the javascript (and allowing non-js broswers to still send the data to the form)

I've also kept the same "value" attributes, since there's not really a unique ID among the values, but probably I would use an unique ID matching the databases' one.

Last but not last, works from IE6 and above (tested), so you shouldn't have any problems on your IE8.

**Markup:**

```
<div id="form-step-1" class="form-step-single">
    <label for="radio-patient"><input class="radiobutton" id="radio-patient" value="PAT" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" /> Patient</label>
    <label for="radio-employee"><input class="radiobutton" id="radio-employee" value="EMPLOYEE" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" /> Employee</label>
    <label for="radio-machine"><input class="radiobutton" id="radio-machine" value="MACHINE" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" /> Machine</label>

    <select class="selectlist hidden" id="ddl-all-templates">
        <option data-type="EMPLOYEE" value="77492|ET_07|EMPLOYEE|08/16/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|70744">Jean Luc Picard</option>
        <option data-type="PAT" value="70470|testing|PAT|08/16/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|70428">Flash Gordon</option>
        <option data-type="PAT" value="70472|testing|PAT|08/12/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Jason Voorhees</option>
        <option data-type="EMPLOYEE" value="70472|testing|EMPLOYEE|08/13/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Freddy Krueger</option>
        <option data-type="PAT" value="70472|testing|PAT|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Darth Vader</option>
        <option data-type="MACHINE" value="70472|testing|MACHINE|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">ED209</option>
        <option data-type="PAT" value="70472|testing|PAT|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Michael Knight</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectlist" id="fakelist" name="AllTemplates">
        <option data-type="EMPLOYEE" value="77492|ET_07|EMPLOYEE|08/16/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|70744">Jean Luc Picard</option>
        <option data-type="PAT" value="70470|testing|PAT|08/16/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|70428">Flash Gordon</option>
        <option data-type="PAT" value="70472|testing|PAT|08/12/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Jason Voorhees</option>
        <option data-type="EMPLOYEE" value="70472|testing|EMPLOYEE|08/13/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Freddy Krueger</option>
        <option data-type="PAT" value="70472|testing|PAT|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Darth Vader</option>
        <option data-type="MACHINE" value="70472|testing|MACHINE|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">ED209</option>
        <option data-type="PAT" value="70472|testing|PAT|08/14/13|08/16/14|Approved|Y|30213">Michael Knight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function () {
    var type = $(this).val();
    $('#fakelist').html('');

    $('#ddl-all-templates option').each(function (index) {
        if (type == $(this).attr('data-type'))
            $(this).clone().appendTo('#fakelist'); 
    });
});
```

And the demo :) http://jsfiddle.net/B6nEs/

**Last edit,** I promise:
The JS could even be smaller:

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function () {
    $('#fakelist').html('');
    $('#ddl-all-templates option[data-type="'+$(this).val()+'"]').each(function() {
        $(this).clone().appendTo('#fakelist'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Mack: Thank you for taking time to implement and test it in IE8. That is awesome. I will test this and will get back to you.

Comment: This has worked without a hiccup. You have saved my life. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.
Errata corrige: I suggest you to change `.attr('selected', true)` to `.prop('selected', true)` since the first one does not pass the correct value when you post the form.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: To create a cross-browser solution you really have to move the options around**

Someone else has already solved the original question so to make this more useful for any future readers, here is a generic version for a select (using data attributes rather than pipe delimited). This jQuery doesn't require an extra hidden select to be created, it will just move the options as hidden siblings of the target select and move them back as required.

http://jsfiddle.net/2msfH/

```
<div id="step1">
    <input class="radiobutton" data-type="PAT" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" /><div>Patient</div>
    <input class="radiobutton" data-type="EMPLOYEE" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" /><div>Employee</div>
    <input class="radiobutton" data-type="MACHINE" name="TemplateTypes" type="radio" /><div>Machine</div>
    <select class="selectLDlist" id="ddlAllTemplates" name="AllTemplates">
        <option value="77492" data-type="EMPLOYEE" data-date="08/16/13">EMPLOYEE</option>
        <option value="70470" data-type="PAT" data-date="08/16/13">Patient</option>
        <option value="70472" data-type="PAT" data-date="08/12/13">Patient</option>
        <option value="70472" data-type="EMPLOYEE" data-date="08/13/13">EMPLOYEE</option>
        <option value="70472" data-type="PAT" data-date="8/14/13">Patient</option>
        <option value="70472" data-type="MACHINE" data-date="08/14/13">MACHINE</option>
        <option value="70472" data-type="PAT" data-date="08/14/13">Patient</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function () {
    var optionsToRemove = $('#ddlAllTemplates option[data-type!=' + $(this).data('type') + ']');
    var optionsToBringBack = $('#ddlAllTemplates ~ option[data-type=' + $(this).data('type') + ']');
    optionsToRemove.hide().insertAfter('#ddlAllTemplates');
    optionsToBringBack.show().appendTo('#ddlAllTemplates');
});
```

`$('#ddlAllTemplates ~ option')` will bring back all siblings  of `#ddlAllTemplates` that match `option`

Comment: Perhaps in your browser, but in Chrome using `:visible` appears not to work when the dropdown isn't expanded.

Comment: People still use Chrome? I just checked, my solution works for Firefox, but not in IE and Chrome since the selector acts weird.

Comment: I think most people still use Chrome :) This does actually make sense if you read about how jQuery decides what elements are `:hidden` and what elements are `:visible`

Comment: I know I selected this as answer since it worked in JSFiddle in Chrome, but what I forgot mentioning is, my browser is IE8 and this solution doesn't work! :(

Comment: Ok, you can't hide options cross browser it seems

Comment: Zac, I preferred you answer, but I had to select the one that worked for me. No hard feelings. :) I thank you as well, since I learnt a lot from our interaction today. Thanks.

Comment: You needn't apologise, I posted something that was clearly wrong (hiding options won't work cross browser and I should have known before posting a solution!). Glad it was useful anyway. I've updated this solution to move and hide the options now without needing any extra markup, although I've kept the example generic and using data attributes as I think that'll be more useful for anyone else later on :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the property for the matched option element in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/animeshb/7Wqfj/) like the following

```
$('#ddlAllTemplates option').each(function () {

    var extract = $(this).attr('value').split('|')[2];
    if (extract == templateType) 
        $(this).prop("selected",true); //Changed line of code
    else 
        $(this).hide();

});
```

Now the DDL shows the value based on the radio button option chosen. You were already 95% through in the sample.

Comment: This doesn't work as intended, you end up losing the other options because they remain hidden.

Comment: Indeed, you should re-add the show(). Also, you are setting all options to selected, which you might not want.

Comment: We can eliminate the else part. It is not of use.

Comment: Initially it appeared to work, but after selecting each dropdown multiple times remaining options are being hidden as Zac mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the selected value after showing/hiding the options:

```
$('#ddlAllTemplates').val($("#ddlAllTemplates option:visible:first").val());
```

See the editted fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wqfj/24/

NOTE: this only works in Firefox as Zac stated. The alternative solution would be:

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function () {
    var templateType = $("#step1 input:radio[class=radiobutton]:checked").attr("dataval");

    var ddlAllTemplates = $('#ddlAllTemplates');
    var options = ddlAllTemplates.find('option');

    var validOption = false;
    $('#ddlAllTemplates option').each(function () {
        var extract = $(this).attr('value').split('|')[2];
        if (extract == templateType) {
            $(this).show();
            validOption = $(this).val();
        }
        else $(this).hide();

    });

    $('#ddlAllTemplates').val(validOption);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Wqfj/26/

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? When changing the radio buttons, the options get swapped out (using the existing script) after which the select-value will be changed to the first available option. The fiddle works like a charm for me...

Comment: In Chrome, `:visible` doesn't work for dropdown options when the dropdown is not expanded, i.e. the elements aren't taking up any screen space

Comment: I've not tested it since you've changed the solution but I believe this will result in the last visible occurrence becoming selected rather than the first. You could fix that with `validOption = validOption ?? $(this).val();` and instatiating validOption with null

Comment: Yes, it will set the last valid option, but the real question is if it matters since the question just needs the wrong answer to go away.

Answer (score -1):

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/7Wqfj/23/) `i think you want like this`

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function () {
    var templateType = $("#step1 input:radio[class=radiobutton]:checked").attr("dataval");


    var ddlAllTemplates = $('#ddlAllTemplates');
    var options = ddlAllTemplates.find('option:contains('+templateType+')').val();


});
```